# Is there a way to tag someone on instagram post and story using InstagramAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using the InstagramAPI for a Python project which requires me to add an instagram post, a story and also tag people on the photo using something like x and y coordinates . All using code!
i use this for uploading:

```
InstagramAPI.uploadPhoto(photo_path, caption=caption)
```

but can't figureout a way to tag people in the post!

Comment: Was the PHP tag an accident?

Comment: No , i saw on other forums that there was a partly working php solution for my problem so maybe someone would know....

Answer (score 0):

Still no luck?

There is API access to post and tag users in a photo.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing/#publish-with-tagged-users

Oddly no one seems to have tried it out publicly.

FB documentation example:

```
POST graph.facebook.com/17841400008460056/media
  ?image_url=https://www.example.com/images/bronzed-fonzes.jpg
  &caption=#BronzedFonzes!
  &user_tags=
   [
     {
       username:'kevinhart4real',
       x: 0.5,
       y: 0.8
     },
     {
       username:'therock',
       x: 0.3,
       y: 0.2
     }
   ]
```